# Android:Running Intent Service Multiple Times

Tags: android, android-intent, service

I want to get multiple rows of database one by one and send it to the service which post the data to server. I am using intent service and to send data I am using bundle.I am calling start Service(Intent Service) in a for loop to send data one by one. Does this make sense? Or is this the right way?

```
String data_returned = sqlcontroller.get_data_sql();


    if (data_returned.equals("No_Data_Found")) {

                } else {
                    try {

                        JSONArray jsonarray = new JSONObject(data_returned).getJSONArray("sql_data");
                        for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
                            coordinates.latitude = (Double) jsonarray.getJSONObject(i).get("latitude");
                            coordinates.longitude = (Double) jsonarray.getJSONObject(i).get("longitude");
                            coordinates.TimeStamp = (String) jsonarray.getJSONObject(i).get("timestamp");
                            Intent myintent = new Intent(context, SendingService.class);
                            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                            bundle.putSerializable("coordinates", coordinates);
                            myintent.putExtras(bundle);
                            context.startService(myintent);
                        }

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }


                }
```

Comment: `data_returned == "No_Data_Found"` is totally wrong.

Comment: Why not build up an `ArrayList` of `coordinates` and call `startService()` once? Though, as Piyush points out, you have bigger problems.

Comment: I cannot make Arraylist of coordinates because the server only accepts the single value of coordinates i.e longitude,latitude and timestamp. I want to send it one by one

Comment: For initial level you are right.But calling service on every for loop its not good coding practice.Do one thing... Take one arraylist and add all the data in that arraylist inside for loop when loop completed pass the arraylist to service and do your operations their.

Comment: @Piyush explanation please how its wrong?

Comment: For comparing strings instead of `==` use `equalIgnoreCase()` or `equals()`. `data_returned == "No_Data_Found"` doesn't fulfill your condition.

Comment: @Piyush Thanks I am editing it

Comment: @AndyDeveloper Okay I am sending the array to the service. Then in service I have to use a for loop to post data depending on length of array is it right to use for loop in OnHandleIntent of Intent Service ?

Comment: @Developer yes it is right.In the service you can use for loop and send your data to server.

Comment: @AndyDeveloper Thank you

Comment: Welcome :) you can raise a flag if you found something useful. thanks